# Как не потерять StackTrace при обработке исключений в try catch finally?

Tags: c#, try-catch

Вопрос в шапке + "что должно быть в блоках catch и finally?".

Мой ответ: насчёт StackTrace не знаю как его не потерять.
Блок `catch`, в нём пишем логику обработки исключения. То есть тот процесс, который должен произойти в случае, если произойдёт какой-то фак-ап. Если блок `catch` не будет найден, то программа завершит процесс аварийно.

Блок `finally` - в данном блоке код срабатывает, как после успешной обработки логики в `try`, так и после обработки исключения в `catch`. Также данный блок можно опустить (finally). В таком случае программа продолжит своё выполнение дальше.

А вот что с StackTrace, как это правильно называется? Трассировка стека ведь правильно будет (из логики вещей). Пожалуйста, расскажите немного об этом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Трассировка стека вызовов - это путь от точки возникновения исключения к точке, где исключение поймано. Когда вы вызываете метод, в стек кладется указатель на точку возврата в текущий метод. Именно по этим указателям и идет сбор данных о цепочке вызванных методов.

Например вам надо обработать исключение и бросить его дальше по стеку, чтобы поймать в каком-нибудь корневом методе, где вы решили ловить и обрабатывать все или почти все исключения, выброшенные из разных концов вашего приложения.

Есть 2 варианта перевыбросить исключение без перегенерации трасстровки.

```
try
{
    // код
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // обработка исключения
    throw;
}
```

То есть если вы бросите `throw ex;`, трассировка начнется начиная с точки текущего выброса, а если `throw;`, то продолжится.

Второй вариант, допустим вы хотите обработать исключение в другом методе, либо в другом блоке кода.

```
ExceptionDispatchInfo edi = null;
try
{
    // код
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
    // обработка исключения
}
// еще какой-то код
edi?.Throw(); // тот самый выброс в другом блоке
```

`ExceptionDispatchInfo` тоже прекрасно консервирует стек вызовов в исключении.

Исключения не только можно обрабатывать и гасить, можно их наполнять отладочной информацией или другими своими данными. Вы можете сами создать свой класс исключения, унаследовав его от `Exception`. Когда поработать с исключением нужно, а гасить его не нужно, именно тогда и требуется повторный выброс этого же исключения, без потери трассировки стека, само собой.

Comment: блестящий ответ, спасибо!